# Assign variable name based on variable string in for loop

Tags: python

```
dblist = ('database1', 'database2', 'database3', 'database4', 'database5', 'database6', 'database7') 
for db in dblist:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select SYSTEM from automation/awdclient where db = " + "'" + db + "'" + "")
    for row in cursor:
        activesystem.db = row[0]
    cursor.close
    conn.close
print activesystem.database1
print activesystem.database2
```

What I am doing is retrieving a system name from a db. I want to assign a variable equal to that system name, with the variable name system.whatever the db string was.

Comment: what is `system`?  I'm guessing that `setattr` is what you're looking for, but it's hard to tell.  Also, I'm guessing you probably need to call `close` on `cursor` and `conn` ... e.g. `cursor.close()`, not `cursor.close`

Comment: Also, depeneding on the use-case ... It is often easier to use a simple `dict` rather than `setattr`.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
activesystem.setattr(db, row[0])
```